# Can I screenshot a world map from Microsoft Bing and use it for Youtube videos?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, copyright-notice

I have this nice screenshot of Microsoft Bing's map, along with the copyright mark at the bottom right corner. For the OpenStreetMap they said it clearly that I must acknowledge/credit them (https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright), but for the others are still unclear.

But can I just use it in my video and also putting the copyright text as the same as in my screenshot?

[image]

Comment: Might depend on where you are and what you're doing with it, but Fair Use might be an option.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be covered under the [Bing Maps Broadcast Terms](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/product/broadcast-terms).

> Subject to the terms of this Broadcast TOU, you may use the Imagery in the Services with television programming and the Road Maps in the Services with television programming, media and entertainment use, all free of charge.

Since you're interested in imagery rather than road maps, you probably aren't permitted to use it.

Comment: OK thanks. Google map allows me though for online videos, http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. It's copyright protected, and the license is not a free one as far as I can tell. If you use openstreetmap *alone* it has a permissible license, and if you provide a copyright text the way they want it (See the openstreetmap website, but also [here](https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use)) you should be fine.